# JSON.Net Deserialize MailAddress

Tags: vb.net, serialization, json.net

I have an object that contains a property called Email which is of type `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`.  I am able to serialize my object with `JSON.Net` and store it in the database.  However, I'm unable to successfully deserialize my object.  The error message I get is:

> Unable to find a constructor to use for type `System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Item1.Email.DisplayName'.

I understand that MailAddress does not have a default constructor and that is why I'm getting this error.  My question is, is there any way around this without converting the property type?  I see there are custom converters, but I haven't had any luck getting JSON.Net to successfully deserialize this one property.

**Update**

Let me elaborate a bit more on what the object looks like and what I've tried.  The object looks something like this:

```
{
  "Item1": {
    "ReceiveNewsletter": false,
    "HomePhone": "074567 8901",
    "SpouseTitle": null,
    "SpouseFirstName": null,
    "SpouseLastName": null,
    "Address": {
      "StreetAddress1": "123 Fake Street",
      "StreetAddress2": null,
      "City": null,
      "State": "QLD",
      "PostalCode": "4627",
      "Suburb": "Abercorn",
      "AustralianAddress": true
    },
    "CustomerAddresses": [],
    "ID": -1,
    "Title": "",
    "FirstName": "James",
    "LastName": "Dean",
    "DisplayName": "James Dean",
    "Email": {
      "DisplayName": "",
      "User": "jamesdean890",
      "Host": "fake.com.au",
      "Address": "jamesdean890@fake.com.au"
    },
    "WorkPhone": null,
    "OtherPhone": "",
    "CellPhone": "0423 456 789",
    "Notes": null
  },
  "Item2": {
    "ID": -1,
    "CustomerID": -1,
    "Pet": {
      "ID": -1,
      "Name": "Fae",
      "Breed": "Puppy Dog",
      "DateOfDeath": "2013-08-28T00:00:00-05:00",
      "ServiceDate": "2013-08-28T00:00:00-05:00",
      "ContactDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00-06:00",
      "PetGender": 1,
      "ReferralClinicID": 462,
      "ReferralPaidDate": null,
      "Row": "\u0000",
      "Plot": -1,
      "CollectedBy": null,
      "DeliverDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00-06:00",
      "DeliveredBy": null,
      "Customer": null,
      "RenewDate": null
    },
    "Service": {
      "ID": -1,
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Price": 285.0,
      "ProductName": "Cremation",
      "ProductID": 1,
      "LineItemState": 0,
      "Plaque": null,
      "IsPlaque": false,
      "Void": false
    },
    "LineItems": [],
    "Notes": "",
    "EnteredBy": null,
    "IsRenewal": false,
    "IsLocked": false,
    "CreateDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00-06:00",
    "OrderTotal": 285.0
  }
}
```

On my contact class I have something like this:

```
<JsonConverter(GetType(EmailConverter))>
Public Property Email() As Net.Mail.MailAddress
    Get
        Return _Email
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Net.Mail.MailAddress)
        _Email = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I then stubbed out a converter something like this:

```
Public Class EmailConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Dim mailAddress As System.Net.Mail.MailAddress = Nothing

        If objectType = GetType(System.Net.Mail.MailAddress) Then
            While reader.Path <> "Item1.Email.Address"
                reader.Read()
            End While

            reader.Read()
            mailAddress = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(reader.Value.ToString)
        End If

        Return mailAddress
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
         Return objectType = GetType(System.Net.Mail.MailAddress)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)

    End Sub
End Class
```

By using the attribute and adding the converter to the serializer, as soon as the serializer hits the Email property it will create a mail object correctly, but any properties after it do not get deserialized properly.

Comment: Show your code and json..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `ReadJson` method leaves the reader incorrectly positioned when it is finished, thus messing up the rest of the deserialization process.

Think of the reader like a forward-only cursor for the JSON data.  When ReadJson gets called, it is positioned such that it is just about to read the next item that the converter said it can handle.  In the case of your `EmailConverter`, it would be positioned just about to read this portion of the JSON:

```
{
  "DisplayName": "",
  "User": "jamesdean890",
  "Host": "fake.com.au",
  "Address": "jamesdean890@fake.com.au"
}
```

Since the converter is supposed to handle the entire `Email` object, it needs to consume *all* the JSON for that object.  I think what is happening is the reader is not getting advanced to the closing brace.  You could probably fix it by continuing to read a little further after you extract the `Address` value, being careful not to go beyond the end of the `Email` object, but this approach is error prone.  A better idea is to use JSON.Net's built-in LINQ-to-JSON facilities to allow you to easily read the entire `Email` object as a chunk, then pick out just the parts you need from it.  This will leave the reader correctly positioned for the rest of the deserialization, and then you don't have to worry about it.  It also greatly simplifies the code.

Here is how I would write the `EmailConverter`:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class EmailConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
        Return objectType = GetType(MailAddress)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Dim jsonObject As JObject = JObject.Load(reader)
        Dim address As String = jsonObject("Address").Value(Of String)()
        Dim mailAddress As MailAddress = New MailAddress(address)
        Return mailAddress
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Brian - Thanks for your example.  However, I tried something like that, but it didn't work.  I've elaborated more in my question above.  What you have will work since you only have one property.  As soon as you start adding other properties then you run into problems.  After looking at the updates I made to the question do you see something that I'm missing?

Comment: Ah, yes, I can see what the problem is now.  I've updated my answer.